# Junk-DNA Tag proposal

Tags: discussion, tags

Quoting @hippietrail

> Would anyone like to add junk-dna and/or noncoding-dna (or should that
>   be non-coding-dna tags? I barely have enough rep here to breathe (-:

I would like to have a tag of this sort but I would propose noncoding-RNA since that is probably the more commonly used term. I can't think of any academic who uses "junk-DNA" in their normal nomenclature outside of a press release.

Comment: Not to worry because Stack Exchange has a concept of "tag synonyms" so when somebody types in "`junk-dna`" as a tag they will instead get "`non-coding-dna`" - perfect! (-: (Sooner or later some non biologist will create the tag here anyway.)

Comment: I completely agree that we should have a non-coding RNA tag. This would this encompass everything from micro RNAs to long non-coding RNAs.